# SVNAnt Trilead jar missing

Tags: svn, ant, svnant

I downloaded and installed SVNAnt 1.3.0, Ant 1.8, and Java 1.6.

When I try to do a simple checkout via https, I get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  com/trilead/ssh2/InteractiveCallback.  I'm not sure why it's using an ssh class since I'm using https.

Trilead SSH for Java doesn't seem to be supported or distributed anymore, and I don't have access to an older version of trilead.jar.

How is everyone else using SVNAnt without trilead.jar?  Does anyone recommend pursuing any other options?  Here is my build script.  The project open and end tags didn't copy over correctly, but they are there when I execute it on my local box.

*Update*  I was able to find trilead.jar in another project's svn repository after some googling, and it did indeed fix the NoClassDefFoundError  It's too bad that Trilead won't distribute the jar.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<property name="svn.base" value="C:\Program Files\svnant\svnant-1.3.0"/>
<property name="svn.lib" value="${svn.base}/lib"/>
<property name="username" value="user"/>
<property name="password" value="password"/>

<path id="svnant.classpath" >
  <fileset dir= "${svn.lib}" >
     <include name= "*.jar" />
  </fileset>
</path>

<typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" classpathref="svnant.classpath" />

<target name="checkout">

   <svn username="${username}" password="${password}" >
      <checkout url="https://svn-server/svn/project" destPath="C:\SVNRepositories\checkout" />
   </svn>

</target>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can download it from here: http://www.findjar.com/jar/com/trilead/trilead-ssh2/build213-svnkit-1.3-patch/trilead-ssh2-build213-svnkit-1.3-patch.jar.html

Truong

Comment: adding that patch .jar to my macbook pro's ant lib folder (/usr/share/java/ant-1.8.2/lib) fixed this issue for me too. for reference, here are my version numbers:
svn: 1.6.16
java: 1.6.0_29
ant: 1.8.2
mac osx: 10.7.2

many thanks for the link and the question!

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove svnkkit.jar from my svnant classpath. I was doing multiple checkouts using subant and the second check out used svnkit instead of javahl. this applied for ant 1.7, java6 and svnant 1.30.

```
<path id="svnant.classpath">
    <fileset dir="./buildBinaries/svnant-1.3.0/lib">
        <include name="*.jar" />
        <exclude name="svnkit.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
<typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" classpathref="svnant.classpath" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I was setting up SVNAnt. I wrote a blogpost that describes how to resolve the issue:

http://www.willjohnson.me/blog/?p=128